# preg_match: nothing to repeat / no match

Tags: php, regex

I am using this: `if(!preg_match('/^+[0-9]$/', '+1234567'))`

and am getting:

> Warning: preg_match()
>   [function.preg-match]: Compilation
>   failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1

any ideas why?

---

**update**: Now using this: `if(!preg_match('/^\+[0-9]$/', '+1234567'))`

and am getting no match.

any ideas why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`+` is a special character that indicates 1 or more of the previous character, and by not escaping it you are applying it to the caret. escape it with `\` and it will match a literal plus sign.

```
if(!preg_match('/^\+[0-9]$/', '+1234567'))
```

**EDIT:**

The reason why it didn't match is because you specified 1 digit from 0-9 and the end of the string with `$`. You need to make it a variable amount of digits.

```
if(!preg_match('/^\+[0-9]+$/', '+1234567')) {
```

Shorter version:

```
if(!preg_match('/^\+\d+$/', '+1234567')) {
```

Comment: Cheers,

Have edited the question now to reflect the current problem.

Comment: Hailwood, you shouldn't remove the old problem, but should show both together. (just edited to do that).

Comment: Also, the current problem is correct behavour - you are asking regex to match a single plus, a single 0..9, then find the end of line position, which your input does not do. To match your supplied input you want either `^\+[0-9]+$` or `^\+[0-9]{7}$` or similar.

Comment: @peter Thanks, will keep that in mind
@meder Cheers, Perfect.

i actually know about the d flag, but use [0-9] for personal preference as i think it increases readability at a glance,

are there any speed benefits to using the flag vs [0-9]?

Answer (score 3):

`'/^\+[0-9]$/'` means that begining of the line has to be plus sign folowed by a number then end of line.

`'/^\+[0-9]+$/'` means that begining of the line has to be plus sign folowed by a **one or more**  numbers then end of line.