# Regex in PHP winth preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using preg_match in PHP together with a REGEX to change the path variable of the string containing:

"any character - paint, old number between one and fourteen - any character"

I put examples of valid strings:

*-paint, old 12*

*-paint, old 0a*

*-paint, old 6b*

...

I have used the preg_match as follows:

```
if(preg_match("/*paint, old ^([1-9]|1[0-4])*/",$ubicacion))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

but it gives me this error: ***preg_match (): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0***

Do you know what is failing?

Comment: Remove `*` and `^` chars. You probably want something like `/\bpaint\s*(\d+[a-zA-Z]*)/`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OjjlDb/1).

Comment: thanks I'll try it, I edited the question that was wrong

Comment: So, you do not need to match anything in `-paint, old 0a`? What is the expected output? See `^.paint,\s+old\s+(1[0-4]|[0-9]).$` at https://regex101.com/r/dQuVR4/1. Does it work as intented?

Comment: The expected output is (1-> true) if it finds a string that is * panit, old [1-14] *, and it would enter the if where I have code to change a variable but I omitted it because the doubt is the REGEX of the match_preg

Comment: i wrote :  if(preg_match("^.paint,\s+old\s+(1[0-4]|[0-9]).$",$ubicacion))  and get this mistake: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: Correct, you should use regex delimiters in `preg_*` functions. See my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preg\_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868876/preg-match-compilation-failed-nothing-to-repeat-at-offset-2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223059/preg-match-nothing-to-repeat-no-match

Comment: It is certainly a different case: no anchor is being quantified here. The asterisks were misused to match any text, and the number pattern could match other numbers than those required. Though the symptoms are related, the solution is rather different than just "escape it properly" as in the two threads mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *`preg_match (): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0`* in most cases is due to the presence of a quantifier at the start of the regex. **A regex cannot start with a quantifier**, i.e. `/+1/`, `/*1/`, `/{2,}1/` and `/{2,5}1/` will throw this error.

You can use

```php
if (preg_match('~\bpaint,\s+old\s+(1[0-4]|[1-9])(?!\d)~i', $string)) {
...
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQuVR4/3) and [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/tVH2b). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `paint,` - `paint,` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  -`old` - an `old` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(1[0-4]|[1-9])` - `1` followed with a digit from `0` to `4` or a non-zero digit
- `(?!\d)` - not followed with any other digit.

Note you do not need to add any patterns at the start and end to actually consume the texts before and after your expected match since all you need is a boolean result.

The `i` at the end makes the pattern match in a case insensitive way.

Comment: thanks, the compiler mistake has disappeared but it doesn't work well ... not change the variable and it should change it in a some cases ... In front of "paint, old" can be many words, such as: "Basement, Left Warehouse, Paint, Old 14a"

Comment: @wiki I added a ["fake" PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/tVH2b), just make sure you insert the right code into the right code blocks. It does not matter what is before the match, `preg_match` finds matches anywhere inside the string.

Comment: thaks, but the value of string can be, for example, this: "Basement, Left Warehouse, Paint, Old 14a". With this valor , it shows: "There is no match!" an i expect : "There is a match". I want in a very long string to find the pattern: paint, old (number between one and fourteen)

Comment: @wiki Add the `/i` flag, `if (preg_match('~\bpaint,\s+old\s+(1[0-4]|[1-9])(?!\d)~i', $string)) {`